# Union de tablas SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, union

estoy intentando realizar una fusión entre las siguientes 2 tablas, llameémoslas Tabla1(izquierda) y Tabla2(derecha).

Lo que me gustaría es poder tener una tabla con los campos: Personal, Hora y Terminal.
El problema viene a que cuando realizo la fusión las horas marcadas en rojo desaparecen y no me deja mostrar el terminal.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que querría conseguir es una salida como la siguiente, donde se puede apreciar que las horas que coincidían se han convertido en solo una y además les ha añadido el campo Terminal de la Tabla2, y las horas de la Tabla1 han sido añadidas también y con un Terminal con otro numero diferente identificativo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahora el codigo que yo tenia es el siguiente:

```
 select distinct t1.personal,t1.hora,t1.terminal 
 from tabla1 t1 
 union all
 select distinct personal,hora,Convert(tinyint,'88') as terminal from Tabla2
```

Muestra lo que quiero pero duplicado ya que no llega a fusionar las tablas debido a que la Tabla 2 ahora contiene un terminal con un numero diferente.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Para ello necesitamos que compartas el esquema de tu tabla (los `CREATE TABLE ...` necesarios) y algunos datos de ejemplo (con tantos `INSERT INTO ...` como sean necesarios). Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En tu sentencia sql utilizas un `UNION ALL` que combina los resultados **incluyendo los duplicados**.

Prueba con `UNION` únicamente.